# Trying to convert all values in a dictionary to int through dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{1: 'rattle', 2: '204', 3: 'three', 4: 404, 5: '104', 6: 'pythonic'}
```

And I want to convert all values to integer, wherever possible, through dictionary comprehension. So I want this:

```
{1: 'rattle', 2: 204, 3: 'three', 4: 404, 5: 104, 6: 'pythonic'}
```

I tried:

```
{i: int(m[i]) for i in m if type(m[i]) == str and m[i].isdigit()}
```

but it includes only those values which are string and can be converted to integer. I have also tried putting the whole thing in a try catch, but it doesn't work

I know this can be done through a simple for loop but is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding an `if` to the end of your loop, you are *filtering*, limiting your output to key-value pairs where the value is a string and consists of digits.

Use a conditional expression in the value expression instead; that way you keep *all* key-value pairs but only apply `int()` to values where this matters and include the rest unchanged:

```
{k: int(v) if isinstance(v, str) and v.isdigit() else v for k, v in m.items()}
```

Rather than just iterate over `m` (and only get the keys), I used `dict.items()` to get both the key and the corresponding value in one step.

Answer (score 1):

```
{k: int(v) if str(v).isdigit() else v for k, v in m.items()}
```